# Receiving JSONDecodeError when trying parse reponse to JSON format

Tags: python, json, request

I am getting JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)',) error when trying to parse response to JSON format

I have tried

```py
resp = requests.get(url=url)
return resp.json()
```

All code

```py
def get_response(self, url):
        resp = requests.get(url=url)
        return resp.json()
```

url = https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=!&prop=langlinks&lllang=hy

I am expecting to parse JSON successfully
Actual result it raises exception

Comment: "HTML is good for debugging, but is unsuitable for application use..."

Comment: Your API is returning raw HTML and not valid JSON check `resp.content`, and try doing `json.loads(resp.content)`

Comment: "Specify the format parameter to change the output format. To see the non-HTML representation of the JSON format, set format=json."

Answer (score 0):

If you download the content from your url, you get an html file, but you actually want to have a json file.
Since you can't parse html with a json parser, you get the error.

Instead, try using this URL (I've added &format=json)

```
url = https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=!&prop=langlinks&lllang=hy&format=json
```